# Hiding Client_id in Springfox Swagger UI - 2.8.0

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, swagger-2.0, springfox

I'm using SpringFox Swagger 2.8.0 with implicit flow. The code is working fine find but when I click Authorize button within the model popup it is showing the client_id like as shown below.

[image]

Can anyone please tell me how to hide that client_id from UI

My swagger configuration is as given below

```
   @Bean
    SecurityConfiguration security() {
      return SecurityConfigurationBuilder.builder()//<19>
          .clientId("test-app-client-id")
          .build();
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityScheme oauth() {
          List<GrantType> grantTypes = new ArrayList<>();
          ImplicitGrant implicitGrant = new ImplicitGrant(new LoginEndpoint("http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html"),"access_code");
          grantTypes.add(implicitGrant);

        return new OAuthBuilder()
                .name("SECURITY_SCHEME_OAUTH2")
                .grantTypes(grantTypes)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Docket docket()
    {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage(getClass().getPackage().getName()))
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()
            .securitySchemes(Collections.singletonList(oauth()))
            .apiInfo(generateApiInfo());
    }
```